# como combinar dos filas de una columna de una tablas en R?

Tags: r

Necesito hacer la siguiente tabla exactamente igual en R:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las unicas formas en que se me ocurrio son las siguientes dos (si bien se asemeja no es exactamente igual):

1)

```
table1<-data.frame(c('Total years of education'),b.c,mean.t)
colnames(table1)<-c('Outcome variable','Birth cohort','Mean')
table1[2,1]<-NA
```

(aca estoy poniendo un NA pero me gustaria combinar los dos casilleros de la fila donde aparece Outcome variable)

2)

```
table1<-data.frame(c('Total years of','education'),b.c,mean.t)
colnames(table1)<-c('Outcome variable','Birth cohort','Mean')
```

este ultimo es lo mas parecido a combinar los dos casilleros que se me ocurrió.

Comment: Bienvenido chipotle19 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Una cosas son los datos y otra es como se los representa. Para una salida como la que muestras hay múltiples paquetes que permiten "dibujar" deforma más elegante cualquier taba. Revisa esto: https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/